# How to send a request one after the other

Tags: android

I want to make a request to the server after getting response for previous one.

```
for (int i = 0; i<imgeURLdb.getallImageInformation().size();i++){

        ImageUploadBean img = new ImageUploadBean();
        img.setImagePath(imgeURLdb.getallImageInformation().get(i).getImagePath());
        img.setFlowid(imgeURLdb.getallImageInformation().get(i).getFlowid());

        String imagePath = img.getImagePath();

        Log.i("imageuploadfile"," image path ----> "+imagePath+" flow id ----> "+imageFlowid);

            UploadImagesToServer.postImage(imagePath);

    }
```

the above code for getting image path from database

public class UploadImagesToServer  {

```
public static  void postImage(String ImageLink){
    final HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    final HttpPost poster = new HttpPost(Constants.MediaUpload);
    poster.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    entity.addPart("file", new FileBody(new File(ImageLink)));
    poster.setEntity(entity);

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){

            try {
                client.execute(poster, new PhotoUploadResponseHandler());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //code to do the HTTP request
        }
    });
    thread.start();
```

}
}

the above code is for making request for server

```
public class PhotoUploadResponseHandler implements ResponseHandler<Object> {
String result = null;


@Override
public Object handleResponse(HttpResponse response)
        throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

    HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();
    String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);


    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseString);
        Iterator<?> keys = jsonObject.keys();
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            String flowid = (String) keys.next();
            String imageURL = (String) jsonObject.get(flowid);

        }

        }catch (JSONException e){

    }
    Log.d("imageuploadfile", responseString);

    return null;
}
```

}

and this is receiving response from server

Comment: what is the issue here?
You can simply request server after getting response in json in responsehandler itself or in the thread created above.

Comment: issue is am receiving url as response and i need to save. one url is belongs to one customer. if i receive multiple url from server. how can i recognize which url is belongs to which customer

Comment: is there any where defined customer related info in URL received?

Comment: @venkateshgowda You need to send some token (identificator) along with your request to server so server can return this one with response for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes i got the solution using **Android Volley synchronous requests**

```
private void getImagePathsFromDB() {


    for (int i = 0; i<imgeURLdb.getallImageInformation().size();i++){

        ImageUploadBean img = new ImageUploadBean();
        img.setImagePath(imgeURLdb.getallImageInformation().get(i).getImagePath());
        img.setFlowid(imgeURLdb.getallImageInformation().get(i).getFlowid());

        String imagePath = img.getImagePath();
        String imageFlowid = img.getFlowid();

        Log.i("imageuploadfile"," image path ----> "+imagePath+" flow id ----> "+imageFlowid);

        RequestFuture<JSONObject> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject.put("file",new File(imagePath));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Constants.MediaUpload, jsonObject, future, future);
        //requestQueue.add(request);
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(request);

        try {
            JSONObject response = future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);// Blocks for at most 10 seconds.
            String imageURL = response.getString("");
            Log.i("imageuploadfile",imageURL+"");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Exception handling
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // Exception handling
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```